# Photo gallery page loading slowy...what could be the problem?

Tags: php, performance

I have a simple php site that I built, but for some reason my photo gallery page takes a little long to load. Can someone tell what the problem is and how to speed up the load time?

Here is php code. By the way I coded everything within this one file (photography.php), with only references to images in another folder...

```
<?php

$thisPage="Photographer, Caribbean, Jamaica, Bahamas - Cheryl Blackerby";

$thisDescription="";

$thisKeywords="Caribbean, Jamaica, Bahamas";

include("header.php");

//include("html/photography.html");

?>

<div id="photography">

        <div id='coin-slider'>

            <div id="photos">

                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img src='photography/img_01.jpg' alt="Staniel Cay Yacht Club in the Exumas, Bahamas" />
                    <span>Staniel Cay Yacht Club in the Exumas, Bahamas</span>
                </a>

                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img src='photography/img_02.jpg' alt="Junkanoo dancer in Inagua, Bahamas" />
                    <span>Junkanoo dancer in Inagua, Bahamas</span>
                </a>

                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img src='photography/img_03.jpg' alt="Doctor's Cave Beach in Montego Bay, Jamaica" />
                    <span>Doctor's Cave Beach in Montego Bay, Jamaica</span>
                </a>

                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img src='photography/img_04.jpg' alt="Paella at the Beach House, Eleuthera, Bahamas" />
                    <span>Paella at the Beach House, Eleuthera, Bahamas</span>
                </a>

                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img src='photography/img_05.jpg' alt="Opening of the Supreme Court, Nassau, Bahamas" />
                    <span>Opening of the Supreme Court, Nassau, Bahamas</span>
                </a>

                <a href="#">
                    <img src='photography/img_06.jpg' alt="Flamingos on Inagua, Bahamas" />
                    <span>Flamingos on Inagua, Bahamas</span>
                </a>    

            </div><!-- end photos -->

        </div>

        <p id="right-description"><img src="images/side-descrip-photos.jpg" width="20" height="90" alt="Photo Description" /></p>


<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#coin-slider').coinslider({ width: 840, height: 520, navigation: true, delay: 5000, links : false, hoverPause: true, opacity: 0.7, effect: 'practice', sph: 1, spw: 1 });
            });
        </script>

    </div><!-- end photography -->

<?php

include("footer.php");

?>
```

Here is the link to the site: [here](http://www.cherylblackerby.com)

I would appreciate any advice on the issue and any coding techniques that would help.

Thanks,

Gary D.

Comment: It's the coin-slider javascript you are using. Even though you have a `photography/img_01.jpg` in your source, the HTML my machine gets has no such `<img>` tag in it. The coin-slider has coded the image into some arcane data and runs it as a program, not an image download. That will make a site seem slow, and the slower the machine, the worse the penalty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loads nice and quickly for me - impressively fast in fact.

I'd say it is bandwidth-heavy, and you tried it from a slow connection.

One thing about it is that you pre-load all your large images, even though you only show the top one.  This is a good idea, except that they appear earlier in your code than the navigation on the right, so I imagine on a slow connection, there'd be some wait for all the large images to download before it shows the navigation on the right.  You could get around this by pre-loading these images using a different method, using JQuery, so that the request to load those images doesn't come before other images on the page.

Comment: Agreed. The only thing making the photography page slightly slower is the ~750 KB of images, and considering the dimensions of those images, I'd say that's not bad at all. Once they've been retrieved and cached, that page is just as speedy as the rest.

Comment: Thank you, that seems like a factor in the load time, but I don't even know where to start with converting this gallery into JQuery. I used a javascript plugin...Do you know how I could do this and have the same functionality as my current plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start here: http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/ that's a firefox plugin that will analyze your page for download bottlenecks. It could have nothing to do with your php code.